# Connecting Microsoft Flow to TFS

Tags: tfs, power-automate

Is there a TFS connector for MS Flow? I only see VSTS connector.

If there is none, is there a way to connect to TFS? I would like to trgger flows when new work items / builds are created in TFS.

Answer (score 2):

If your TFS server supports Service Hooks, 2015 or better, then you can [configure a custom service hook receiver for Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/call-flow-restapi/). [More details on setting up a service hook from the TFS side can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=vsts).

Your TFS server version must be at least 2015 in order to configure service hooks. Looking at the tags, your TFS version (2013) is too old, unfortunately. Given that support on TFS 2013 expires in about a year, it may be a good time to start the upgrade to TFS 2018 or a migration to VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scenario you could look at connecting to the SQL DB behind your TFS instance directly using Flow and the on-premises data gateway. More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/gateway-reference

Comment: Unfortunately I cant use that option. Im just a regular TFS user so Im looking at an approach similar to VSTS connector.